# Click on image to play sound PHONEGAP

Tags: javascript, android, image, cordova, onclick

I am clicking on my image to call the `playAudio()`. I am using phonegap to do this.

Here is my function

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


        // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;


        // Play audio
        //
        function playAudio(src) {
            if (my_media == null) {
                // Create Media object from src
                my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
            } // else play current audio
            // Play audio
            my_media.play();



        }





        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

        // onError Callback 
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }


        </script>
```

Here is my image

```
<input type="image" id="myimage" src="numb/equal.png" style="height:100px;width:100px;margin-top:0px" onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/www/Mobile/sound/'+ abc +'.mp3');"/>
```

On clicking this image it should play the corresponding mp3. But in my console I am getting "Media is not Defined"

[Here is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkTQ8.png)

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be new [Audio()](http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/)

Comment: I have tested with Audio tag in html5 too , worked perfectly in browser but not in phone.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Phoengap/Cordova, you shouldn't include `/android_asset/www/` in the path to the mp3. You can think of that `/android_asset/www/` folder as the 'context root' - all relative URLs will automatically have this appended to them.

So just change `onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/www/Mobile/sound/'+ abc +'.mp3');"` to
`onclick="playAudio('./Mobile/sound/'+ abc +'.mp3');"` and it should find the correct path to your audio.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt do it this way. With HTML5 you can play audio files very easily with the [AUDIO TAG](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_audio.asp). Make your javascript create the element that is described and set the autoplay property.

Comment: I have tested with Audio tag in html5 too , worked perfectly in browser but not in phone.

Comment: I am pretty sure the `audio` tag will not work in a cordova/phonegap project because the native web view that cordova uses does not support some/many HTML5 elements, and I'm pretty sure audio is one of these. Maybe now that Android webivew uses Chromium we will see audio tag working soon, but given the history of the Webview team, I wouldn't count on it.